# Creating a 2 page website ( index.html & another.html ) using Webpack and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I want to set up a web page that is two pages(multiple in the long run, but just 2 for this example). The first page looks like this picture and just has a link that says "Click Me". When you click this link, it takes you to the second webpage which says "Hello World".

[image]

I can get the webpage working for a website with one page. It uses this webpack.config.js file

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackTemplate = require('html-webpack-template');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I tried modifying this config file, so that I could have multiple pages. You can see the modifications in the following config file, which I modified based on [these instructions](https://www.ivarprudnikov.com/static-website-multiple-html-pages-using-webpack-plus-github-example/)

**webpack.config.js for multiple pages**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackTemplate = require('html-webpack-template');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    services: '../src/services.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/services.html',
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['services'],
        filename: 'services.html'
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

I receive the following output error when using the latter webpack.config.js file

```js
Jacob-Air:Dir Jacob$ npm start

> default@1.0.0 start Dir/Dir_html
> webpack-dev-server

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from Dir/Dir_html
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 7e17e6d8bd9ec606703d
Version: webpack 4.35.0
Time: 2547ms
Built at: 06/28/2019 11:09:27 AM
        Asset       Size    Chunks             Chunk Names
   index.html  629 bytes            [emitted]  
     index.js   1.25 MiB     index  [emitted]  index
services.html  752 bytes            [emitted]  
  services.js    359 KiB  services  [emitted]  services
Entrypoint index = index.js
Entrypoint services = services.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ./src/index.js 40 bytes {index} [built]
[1] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ../src/services.js 40 bytes {services} [built]
[./es6/Banner.js] 1.7 KiB {index} [built]
[./es6/Footer.js] 345 bytes {index} [built]
[./es6/Header.js] 579 bytes {index} [built]
[./es6/HomePageServices.js] 3.4 KiB {index} [built]
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {index} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {index} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {index} {services} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost 4.29 KiB {index} {services} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {index} {services} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {index} {services} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.77 KiB {index} {services} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {index} {services} [built]
[./src/index.js] 534 bytes {index} [built]
    + 35 hidden modules

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/services.js' in 'Dir/Dir_html'

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ../src/services.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/services.js' in 'Dir/Dir_html'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost ../src/services.js services[1]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html] 789 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "services.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = services.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/services.html] 909 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

---

**OTHER FILES THAT MAY BE USEFUL**

**src/index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Content = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <a src='./about.html'>Click Me</a>
            </div>            
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

const root = document.getElementById('Content');
ReactDOM.render (
    <Content />,
    root
)
```

**src/services.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Content = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <span>Hello World</span>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

const root = document.getElementById('Content');
ReactDOM.render (
    <Content />,
    root
)
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "default",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "html-webpack-template": "^6.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
```

**Both index.html and services.html**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Web Dexter</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myCss">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.00, maximum-scale=1.10, minimum-scale=0.80">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='Content'></div>
  </body>
  <script src='./bundle.js'></script>
</html>
```

**File hierarchy**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this in entry:

```
entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    services: './src/services.js'
  },
```